# How to select a certain key value and skip if a certain key is not present in the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

```
 d =  [{'email': 'harimsri@math.uvic.ca', 'gid': '5b869a4fe1cd8e14a38d67b5', '_id': '53f49508dabfaeb4c677b4a4', 'name': 'Hiromasa Habuchi', 'org': 'Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Victoria, Victoria, BC, V8W 3R4, Canada', 'orgid': '5f71b2841c455f439fe3c6c9'}, {'_id': '53f43522dabfaee4dc7780b2'}, {'_id': '560175f745cedb3395e5a530'}]
```

d is the list of dictionaries. I want to select the key['name'] value. Since other dictionaries in the list don't have a key['name'] so I want to skip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension that will check for each dictionary if the key `name` belongs to the dictionary list of keys.

```
dicts =  [{'email': 'harimsri@math.uvic.ca', 'gid': '5b869a4fe1cd8e14a38d67b5', '_id': '53f49508dabfaeb4c677b4a4', 'name': 'Hiromasa Habuchi', 'org': 'Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Victoria, Victoria, BC, V8W 3R4, Canada', 'orgid': '5f71b2841c455f439fe3c6c9'}, 
          {'_id': '53f43522dabfaee4dc7780b2'}, 
          {'_id': '560175f745cedb3395e5a530'}]

[d for d in dicts if 'name' in d.keys()]
```

Output:

```
[{'_id': '53f49508dabfaeb4c677b4a4', 
  'email': 'harimsri@math.uvic.ca',
  'gid': '5b869a4fe1cd8e14a38d67b5',
  'name': 'Hiromasa Habuchi',
  'org': 'Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Victoria, Victoria, BC, V8W 3R4, Canada',
  'orgid': '5f71b2841c455f439fe3c6c9'}]
```